# mpd watchdog on raspberry pi

Tags: bash, mpd

I would like to use `mpd-watchdog` from [JackRichardson](https://discourse.mopidy.com/t/radio-doesnt-return-after-internet-dropout-mpd-watchdog/424/8) on a Raspbian Buster Lite. Copying the files to the relevant directories is no problem. Only `update-rc.d`, `mpd-watchdog` defaults I think that's something for Debian. The question is does this work on a raspberry? Or how should I do this for a Raspberry Pi?

Or doesn't work this script at all on a raspberry?

Comment: Hello and welcome to this community. || "*The question is does this work on a raspberry?*" Why don't you test it completely? And, If you followed the instruction on the link, what's the problem? || What's your goal of using `mpd-watchdog`? Update the question would be helpful.

Comment: The intention is if the internet has a dropout to restart the stream where you listen to. I just copied the files to the correct directories and gave mpd-watchdog execute rights and tested them. And unfortunately the stream is not restarted after a dropout. I am now searching where the logs are written to see what happens. I just can't find them yet. With not really known with Linux ...

Comment: I cannot find anything in the log files. Looks like mpd watchdog isn't even started.

Comment: Why don't you run the standalone "Pi MusicBox" on the raspberry pi?

Comment: I've already tried that. But that doesn't also work for me if there are internet dropouts. And there is a lot of unnecessary junk that I don't need at all.

Comment: Alright. If you'll don't get an answer, you should ask a new question about "**what exactly you want**" on Superuser/Linux & Unix/Raspberry Pi SE sites.